# Running a script Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, command, disk

I am trying to run the command:
`$ sudo ./mk2partsd /dev/sdb`

mk2partsd is this file:
https://github.com/gumstix/meta-gumstix-extras/blob/dizzy/scripts/mk2partsd

I get this error:

> sudo: ./mk2partsd: command not found

mk2partsd is saved on my Desktop and a navigate there with cd Desktop
I tried saving the file with the extentions of .c and .sh and running but same output

Comment: You should be calling the actual filename. If you called it xxx.c then sudo xxx.c - but why you added a random .c to the end I have no idea. .sh makes more sense - sudo xxx.sh. Another possibility would be a corrupt `#!` at the start of the file (I haven't looked at the file)

Answer (score 0):

1. Most probably your script file is not executable. Make it executable with `chmod u+x ./mk2partsd` and try again.
2. Alternatively, start the script as a parameter to the shell: `sudo sh ./mk2partsd /dev/sdb`.
3. The name or extension of the file do not matter, but `.sh` would be the best.